# Solr/Solrj pagination with cursor

Tags: pagination, cursor, solrj

I would like to ask how to fetch all doc from solr collection using solrJ.
I have written one code but getting error
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No collection param specified on request and no default collection has been set.

```
String zkHostString = "linux152:2181,linuxUL:2181,linux170:2181/solr";
CloudSolrClient server = new CloudSolrClient(zkHostString); 
SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery(); 
public void cursorMark() throws  IOException, SolrServerException {
    SolrQuery parameters = new SolrQuery();     
    QueryResponse response = new QueryResponse();
     response = server.query(parameters);
    parameters.set("q",":");
    parameters.set("qt","/select");
    parameters.setParam("wt","json"); 
    parameters.set("collection", "RetailDev_Protocol");
    int fetchSize = 2;
    parameters.setRows(fetchSize);
    String cursorMark = CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_START;
    boolean done = false;
    while (! done) {
        parameters.set(CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_PARAM, cursorMark);

      long offset = 0;
      long totalResults = response.getResults().getNumFound();

      while (offset < totalResults)
      {
          parameters.setStart((int) offset);  

          try {
            for (SolrDocument doc : server.query(parameters).getResults())
              {
                   log.info((String) doc.getFieldValue("title"));
              }
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

          offset += fetchSize;
      }

    String nextCursorMark = (response).getNextCursorMark();



}
    SolrDocumentList list = response.getResults();
    System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Implement correctly pagination in Solr is quite hard, I have written a post about, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992296/solr-solrj-pagination/37648027#37648027

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your collection in the following way:

```
server.setDefaultCollection("<MY_COLLECTION");
```

otherwise you get the error that you specified in your question.

Comment: Great @shalu, please remember to accept and/or up vote the answer.